# problem with texture rendering

Tags: rendering

I know that this is probably something simple, but when i render my project, I do not have any texture. The object remains completely black. I spend hours trying to understand, but still the same problem. I think it have something to do with the node stuffs, I do not understand much of it.

Here's the texture:
[image: image texture]

Here's the .blend:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your object has three materials.

Go into edit mode, then select the materials one after each other and press the <kbd>select</kbd> and <kbd>deselect</kbd> buttons to find out, which material is assigned to the object. Right now, only the first material *mug.002* is assigned to the object.

[image]

This material is set up wrong. It you can not plug a color output in the **Surface** - input of the **Material Output** node. The **Surface** input needs a **BSDF** output, like from the *Diffuse BSDF* node.

[image]

Fortunately, you already have a properly set up material for the object: *Material*. In edit mode, select all vertices <kbd>A</kbd>, then select the material *Material* and press <kbd>Assign</kbd>.

[image]

The material will show correctly.

[image]